# How to filter entities in View by all of their taxonomy term reference fields?

Tags: views, entities, 8

Let's say I have a custom entity that has two taxonomy reference fields: **categories** and **tags**. And I want to display all entities that have taxonomy term with id 1. The term is a dynamic value(contextual filter) so it can be either the category or tag.

How can I do that in Views? Right now I can filter categories or tags separately but I need to filter both of them.

If I use two filters they will cancel each other because each of them have, in my case, "Display contents of "No results found"" set.

Comment: How is this Drupal 8 specific?

Comment: in d7 there is filter for all taxonomy terms associated with a node. though I can'remember it's name, but it's in the core.

Comment: Then it is in D8 as well, as all functionality was moved in.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot? I was not able to find it. I didn't even know it was in D7(since I haven't been using Views for a while) but someone mentioned it on irc so I've looked and it actually is in D7 Views. But not in D8(at leas I haven't found it).

Answer (score 0):

You can get an argument from url with views.

Use Provide default value in the contextual filter.

[image]

Another way (in drupal 7)would be to use this module: https://drupal.org/project/views_url_path_arguments

Comment: You didn't understood my question. I know how to use contextual filters. I'm asking how to use one argument for all taxonomy term reference fields an entity has.

Comment: Ok, so use one argument for multiple filters?

Comment: I can't because if one field won't return results it will hide the whole View.